# Issue with the lost listener of the observable

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I have some issue with the lost listener of the observable subject in the service. When the application is initialized for a while it works fine - it responds to messages from the web socket connection, the handler of these messages is executed. But for some unknown reason at some point in time the listener of the observable subject disappears from the list of subscribers.

I tried debugging this issue and found that my observable's list of `messages$` stream subscribers is empty when a message from a web socket is received.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { filter, takeUntil } from "rxjs/operators";
import { SocketService } from "./services/socket.service";
import { NgOnDestroy } from "./utils/ng-on-destroy";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [NgOnDestroy]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private ngOnDestroy: NgOnDestroy,
    private socketService: SocketService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socketService.messages$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngOnDestroy),
        filter((data: any) => !!data.method)
      )
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        // ... some code
      });
  }
}
```

socket.service.ts:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketService {

  private ws: WebSocket | null = null;

  open$ = new Subject();

  messages$ = new Subject();

  constructor() {
  }

  public send(data: any): void {
    this.ws?.send(
      JSON.stringify(data)
    );
  }

  public connect(): void {
    try {
      this.ws = new WebSocket(`wss://${window.location.host}/notifications`);

      this.ws.addEventListener('open', _ => {
        this.open$.next();
      });

      this.ws.addEventListener('message', (message: MessageEvent) => {
        this.messages$.next(
          JSON.parse(message.data)
        );
      });

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('WEBSOCKET CONNECTION ERROR!!!');
    }
  }

  public close(): void {
    this.ws?.close();
  }
}
```

ng-on-destroy.ts:

```
import { Injectable, OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { Subject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class NgOnDestroy extends Subject<null> implements OnDestroy {
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.next(null);
    this.complete();
  }
}
```

I don't understand the reason why this could happen, since I don't have an explicit unsubscribe anywhere in my code except for the `NgOnDestroy` class. Although I don't really know, I don't believe the unsubscribe happens in it, assuming the `AppComponent` is never destroyed. Can you please help me figure this out?

Comment: Your naming of a service NgOnDestroy is if nothing else confusing. If you remove the takeUntil(this.ngOnDestroy) I have a feeling your problem will go away. If you are trying to manage the subscription lifecycle I suggest doing it differently or at least with less confusing/redundant names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I figured out exactly what happens to the subscription object: an exception occurs during the execution of the message handler, which causes the subscription to close.

Comment: I have the same problem, how did you find the exception?